# Why is the top bar showing too much rep?

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar

**Help! What is happening!?**

Here on Meta today I have been having a very strange issue with the top bar. It has been showing 10 more rep than I really have, on all pages which have not been refreshed in a while. When I reload the page however, it goes back to the correct value. Take a look at this screenshot. It says on the top bar that I have 91 rep, but if you look on the dropdown menu or my profile you will see that I only really have 81 rep. (My rep level has already changed, but long after I began writing this.)

This also happened in the dropdown menu of other sites under the Stack Exchange icon. The circled item in the list (Raspberry Pi SE) showed 2 too much rep (in this shot it is the correct value) but all the others had the right value!

[image]

I haven't been downvoted, or had anything deleted take a look at this screenshot of my rep history.

[image]

I have absolutely no idea what is going on here. What is happening? Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: I explained that in the question. There was also an issue with the rep there.

Comment: I still blame caching.

Comment: Those values are cached for at least 10 minutes. See the duplicate for a bit more detail on how they're updated.